# Ubuntu terminal not showing path

Tags: bash, profile

I have added one line in bashrc and after that terminal is not working as expected, no path is showing and I am unable to run any command:
Below line i have added in bashrc:

```
. ~/.profile
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The line you added tells `~/.bashrc` to *source* `~/.profile`. However, Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` is set up to source `~/.bashrc`. So you just set up an infinite loop: `~/.bashrc` is sourcing `~/.profile` which is sourcing `~/.bashrc` which is sourcing `~/.profile` and so on, for ever. Since `~/.bashrc` is read every time you open a new terminal, it enters this infinite loop, never exits and therefore leaves you with the problem you see.

Since you can log in graphically, just use a GUI editor to remove the line, as others suggested, and you will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.bashrc` using a GUI editor, geany for example, and remove the line you added. There must be some GUI editor installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried i opened /etc/bash.bashrc but this file seems different. and the line is not in this file

Comment: Apparently you edited `~/.bashrc`. It's the user's bashrc, not the global `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Try to edit this file.

Comment: @KumarHarsh please don't edit `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Open the file browser and press Ctrl+H to show hidden files. You should see `.bashrc` right there in your home directory. Click to open with Gedit or whatever text editor wants to open it and remove that line you added.

Comment: Thanks @Zanna it is in home directory.

Answer (score -3):

New start (I really have not the ability of multitask). Boot in recovery-mode

```
mv /home/your-user-name/.bashrc home/your-user-name/.bashrc.bak
```

afterwards cp the default file

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc  /home/your-user-name/.bashrc
```

Then you have to change ownership of that new file.

```
chown your-user-name:your-user-name /home/your-user-name/.bashrc
```

reboot.

Comment: He couldn't do that, he wasn't able to type any commands, no prompt :)

Comment: okay,  it is better to rename the broken $HOME/.bashrc.

Comment: Yes, renaming would be better, but the main issue is that the OP can't run any commands because their shell never finishes initializing since they have set it to go into an infinite loop. So no command can be a solution, unless you also explain how to log in as a different user or using a different shell so commands can be executed again.

Comment: You don't need to change the ownership, you copied it as your user so it will be created with the right permissions. But in any case: the OP can't do any of these things if you don't also explain how they can get around the fact that they currently can't open a terminal and run any commands.

Comment: In recovery-mode?